# win32 SetForegroundWindow in haskell

Tags: windows, haskell

I've noticed the [Haskell Win32 api](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/Win32/2.2.2.0/doc/html/Graphics-Win32-Window.html) does not have a `SetForegroundWindow` function and I'm not skilled enough in haskell to add this feature myself. Would there be any way to replicate this using haskell or has any one made their own wrapper using ffi?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a simple wrapper using the FFI:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ForeignFunctionInterface #-}

module SetForegroundWindow
( setForegroundWindow
) where

import Foreign
import Graphics.Win32

foreign import stdcall safe "windows.h SetForegroundWindow"
    c_setForegroundWindow :: HWND -> IO Bool

setForegroundWindow :: HWND -> IO Bool
setForegroundWindow = c_setForegroundWindow
```

Comment: awesome! you should contribute this to the win32 github page,https://github.com/haskell/win32/blob/master/Graphics/Win32/Window.hsc

Comment: @pyCthon but why don't you contribute it by yourself?

Comment: @ДМИТРИЙМАЛИКОВ МАЛИКОВ I don't want so take credit for his work